# RF transceiver and antenna near LiPo battery?

Tags: rf, lipo

Would there be any foreseeable issues with placing a ~300mAh LiPo battery within 10 or so millimeters of an RF transceiver and antenna?

[image: sketch of mechanical arrangement]
Units are in milimeters.  (Click for larger image.)

Comment: Do you own a cellphone?

Comment: just wanted to check.  Usually millimeters can make large differences when it comes to RF.

Comment: It depends.  Probably, it would be alright.  Just in case, post a sketch of your mechanical arrangement, please.

Comment: http://imgur.com/5EzXRRy units are in milimeters @NickAlexeev

Comment: Not if the RF power is 100 watts.

Comment: No foreseeable issues. Only unforeseeable ones...

Answer (score 1):

I should not think that there would be a problem as your RF radiating antenna would be well clear of the small LiPo battery. But if you wanted to be absolutely sure then use a internally screened plastic case to house your project.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a problem unless the radiating patter is going past your battery. Of course, if that were the case, you'd have much bigger problems (Hint, there's a chip there that wouldn't like it).